# MySQL BEFORE UPDATE trigger - change value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So, I've got a MySQL table, named employees.

```
ID    name    meta
0     jack    ok
1     anne    del
```

I want to write a trigger which prevents a row where meta='del' to update the meta field.
So, if I do:

```
UPDATE employees SET meta = 'busy' WHERE ID = 0
```

The row should be updated and meta would be 'busy'

But when I do:

```
UPDATE employees SET meta = 'busy' WHERE ID = 1
```

The meta field should still be 'del'

I tried:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateEmployees
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.meta = 'del' THEN
        NEW.meta = 'del'
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

But MySQL returns with an syntax error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 28):

You forgot to add the SET clause. This way it doesn't actually change the value.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateEmployees
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.meta = 'del' THEN
        SET NEW.meta = 'del';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed `;`

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateEmployees
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.meta = 'del' THEN
        NEW.meta = 'del';   -- << here
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

*TRIGGER IS EVIL*.

An alternative to trigger is by adding another condition `AND`

```
UPDATE employees 
SET    meta = 'busy' 
WHERE  ID = 1 AND meta <> 'del'
```

Comment: The trigger still doesn't work but I decided to go with your second solution. Thank you!

Comment: Why is TRIGGER evil?  It is a very powerful tool which database admins can use to enforce data integrity rules.  In an environment where data integrity is paramount (corporate records for example) Triggers provide a valuable resource for enforcing that, even on application developers.  I use triggers now even in my personal development as they enforce data integrity for me at a small performance overhead, which would be lost anyways by the application doing the same checking...

Answer (score 0):

simple logic, check first those column value declare unique in db (may use concat and where clause pk id). if not exist then continue update and set value include the unique constraint column stated, else (if exist) update only column that not declare in unique constraint. logic may check on page or can run on stored procedure. leave the trigger alone.